# Similarity of Images (CBIR) for two different cameras

Tags: object-detection

Suppose we have a top down picture of an object (let's say it is a shoe) from an overhead camera. Also suppose we have a database of various objects from a closeup camera. If we feed the top-down picture of the hsoe into a CBIR model, then this picture would obviously have very low similarity with the images in the database. But would the image with the highest similarity score in the database still be a shoe even though the absolute score is small?